# 'Duplicate local variable msg2' error

Tags: eclipse

I am doing a Minecraft Plugin in order to learn something new. Im quite new to java. Could somebody explain why I am receiving this error and how to fix it ?

Code: http://pastebin.com/kSdAkt5j

Same error in line: 64,70,79,86,92. "Duplicate local variable msg2"

Comment: you can't create a duplicate variable names in Java with in a scope

Comment: How can i fix it ?

Comment: @Sh0oter rename the second `msg2` to a different name.

Answer (score 0):

```
String msg2 = Lang.MSG_USAGE;
      msg2 = msg2.replace("{USAGE}", getUsage());
      return Util.sendMsg(player, msg2);
    case -934610812:
      if (s2.equals("remove")) {
        break label621;
      }
 String msg2 = Lang.MSG_USAGE;  --> this is WRONG as its already declared above
 msg2 = msg2.replace("{USAGE}", getUsage());
 return Util.sendMsg(player, msg2);
```

you have two choices:

1) make  `String msg2 = Lang.MSG_USAGE;` to just `msg2 =
    Lang.MSG_USAGE;This one will work in your code as`Lang.MSG_USAGE;` is returning a new value each time you call, you can use the existing variable name (msg2).

2) create second occurrence with different variable
    name. `String msg2 = Lang.MSG_USAGE;` to `String msg99 = Lang.MSG_USAGE;`

Comment: I tried option 1 with changing String, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: change in the line 64?infact you can use it in all error lines you mentioned.

Comment: So for example:
`String msg2 = Lang.MSG_USAGE`; to `String msg = Lang.MSG_USAGE;`
then in next error line:
`String msg2 = Lang.MSG_USAGE;` to `String msg3 = Lang.MSG_USAGE;`
Am I right?

Comment: yes you can also do that , in that case you actually giving new name for declaration.i.e., Option 2

Comment: I think I am too stupid to understand option 1. Haha ^^ 
Thank you for the time you spent for these explanations.
 If you have few minutes more, could you explain method 1 more clearly? :D

Comment: i updated the examples.if you found the above answered the problem. accept as answer.

Comment: After changing `String msg2 = Lang.MSG_USAGE;` to `String msg = Lang.MSG_USAGE;` it says "msg2 cannot be resolved into variable"
This code is so annoying. I tried everything :/

Comment: use String msg2 = Lang.MSG_USAGE; to msg2 = Lang.MSG_USAGE;

Comment: Now there are errors in lines: 55,62,77,84 - "The label label621 is missing" and "The label label674 is missing" and in line 109 "Unreachable code"
Now code looks like this: http://pastebin.com/0DLUCV1A

Comment: its a different error,check the syntax for switch statement .you have declared label outside switch.